# Table update with aggregate by person

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of students, and I want to update a field with each student's attendance information.

My naive attempt was

```
UPDATE Student
SET CurrentAttendance = COUNT(AttendanceID)
FROM Student INNER JOIN Attendance ON Student.StudentID = Attendance.iStudentID
```

But of course you can't update using an aggregate.

I found this solution:

```
UPDATE Student
SET CurrentAttendance = q.COUNTID
FROM (SELECT COUNT(AttenanceID) AS COUNTID 
      FROM Student INNER JOIN Attendance 
      ON Student.StudentID = Attendance.StudentID) q
```

While this runs without error, it's obviously wrong. Every student has the same attendance count which appears to be the count of **all** the students.

How can I run this update so that it updates each student with **only** that student's attendance count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  If you want to update *all* students, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Student
SET CurrentAttendance = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM Attendance 
                         WHERE Student.StudentID = Attendance.iStudentID
                        );
```

This will update *all* students, even those with no records in `Attendance`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Get the `COUNT()` grouped by `StudentID` within a derived table, then join back to `Student`:

```
UPDATE S
SET CurrentAttendance = AttendanceCount
FROM Student S
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(AttendanceID) as AttendanceCount, StudentID
            FROM Attendance
            GROUP BY StudentID) A on A.StudentID = S.StudentID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Group By` and a `Where`

```
UPDATE Student
SET CurrentAttendance = q.COUNTID
FROM (SELECT COUNT(AttenanceID) AS COUNTID, StudentID
      FROM Attendance 
      Group by StudentID) q
WHERE StudentID = q.StudentID
```